# how to make a for loop countdown in time format? and how can I put/ code if the user want a specific time they want?

Tags: for-loop, timer, countdown

My question: > how to make a for loop countdown in time format? and how can I put/ code if the user wants a specific time they want?

> I don't know what's wrong with my reset button...
> I just want somebody to help me in the input part because I really don't know how to start my code there. I just don't get the loops. thank you!

```js
function showingLoop() {

      for (let counter = 0; counter <= 60; counter += 1) {
        setTimeout((`clockInSeconds(${60 - counter})`), counter * 1_000)
      }
    }
    
    function clockInSeconds(seconds) {
      let timeDiv = document.querySelector('#time')
      timeDiv.innerHTML = String(seconds)
    }
    
    function showingReset() {
            document.getElementById('reset').reset();
        }
```

```css
#time {
      font-family: 'Red Hat Mono';
      font-size: 56px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&family=Red+Hat+Mono:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Countdown</title>
  </head>

<body>
  <div id=hours>
    <input type=number>h
  </div>
  <div id=minutes>
    <input type=number>m
  </div>
  <div id=seconds>
    <input type=number>s
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="showingLoop()">Start</button>
  <button id="reset" onclick="showingReset()">Reset</button>

  <div id="time">

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create a target date from the user inputs and then refresh the displayed date while the time delta from now to then is > 0.

```js
// Reference to interval
    var intervalVar = null;

    function showingLoop() {
        // Clear interval if not null
        if (intervalVar != null) clearInterval(intervalVar);
        // Get user input
        var element = document.getElementById('hours').getElementsByTagName('input')
        const hours = parseInt(element[0].value == "" ? 0 : element[0].value);
        element = document.getElementById('minutes').getElementsByTagName('input')
        const minutes = parseInt(element[0].value == "" ? 0 : element[0].value);
        element = document.getElementById('seconds').getElementsByTagName('input')
        const seconds = parseInt(element[0].value == "" ? 0 : element[0].value);
        // Parse user input into target date
        var tempDate = new Date();
        tempDate.setTime(tempDate.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        tempDate.setTime(tempDate.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        tempDate.setTime(tempDate.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));

        var targetDate = tempDate.getTime();
        // Create Interval which calls inteself every 1000ms and updates until it reaches target date
        intervalVar = setInterval(() => {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            // Find delta time between now and target date
            var deltaTime = targetDate - now;
            // Parse milliseconds into human reable formats
            var days = Math.floor(deltaTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((deltaTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((deltaTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((deltaTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            // If the count down is finished, clear Interval and write 0s
            if (deltaTime < 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalVar);
                days = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
            }
            clockInSeconds(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function clockInSeconds(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
        let timeDiv = document.querySelector('#time')
        timeDiv.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    }

    function showingReset() {
        clearInterval(intervalVar);
        showingLoop();
    }
```

Note that I replaced `setTimeout(...);` with `setInterval(...);`.
I did this because with `setTimeout(...);` in a for loop you "instantly" queue up every HTML edit and to my knowledge can't quickly just get rid of them all. With the new function it will wait 1000ms between edits and because we are keeping a reference to it we can easily reset it.

The idea for using `setInterval(..);` originates from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp). Check it out if interested!

EDIT:

- replaced original code using async and await with `setInterval(...);`
- Forgot to give credits